# C++, fast removal of elements from vector by binary index

Tags: c++, erase-remove-idiom

There are several posts focused on the fast removal of elements given by indices from a vector. This question represents a slightly modified version of the problem.

There is a vector of elements:

```
std::vector <double> numbers{ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600 };
```

and the corresponding binary index:

```
std::vector<bool> idxs{ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
```

What is the fastest method of removal of elements with the "zero indices" from the vector? It may contain millions of elements.

I tried experiments with `remove_if()`, but this is not correct:

```
numbers.erase(std::remove_if(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [](bool b)->bool
    {
        return b == 1;
    }), numbers.end());
```

Comment: `index` seems to be a misnomer here.

Comment: Perhaps a vector isn't the correct container type for this use case? What else are you doing with the data?

Comment: What exactly is a "binary index"? Your question is not clear.

Comment: If you want to remove items from `number` based on the values  in `idxs`, you'll have to use `idxs` an keep it in synch with `numbers`.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude: This data I received as a result of some spatial analysis. I would like to use its subset for further computations. The structure is more complicated but works well as an illustrative example.

Comment: If you're single-threaded, take two indices `from` and `to`, increase `to` in each step and `from` only if `!idxs[from]` in the loop. inside the loop, swap `numbers[from]` with `numbers[to]` if `idxs[from]` && `from != to`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no automatism for this. You simply have to implement a custom erase function yourself:

```
auto widx = numbers.begin();
for (auto ridx = numbers.cbegin(), auto bidx = idxs.cbegin();
     ridx != numbers.end;
     ++ridx, ++bidx) {
  if (*bidx) *widx++ = *ridx;
}
numbers.erase(widx, numbers.end());
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was concerned about :-)

Comment: Copying a double needlessly is likely cheaper than paying for the branch. So `*widx = *ridx; widx += static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(*bidx);`. But the compiler might figure this out on its own. Benchmark if this is critical. Also if speed, then `std::vector<bool>` might be a bottleneck. A vector of `ptrdiff_t` is possibly faster.